# Rolebased logins using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Just a fast question. 
Do you think it is possible to create a rolebased login system using Localstorage i Javascript? without using any libaries or frameworks(not allowed)? My approach is to create a "User" class, with 2 different authorization levels, that will redirect to two different html sites :)

```
class userLogin{
    constructor(username, password, authLevel){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.authlevel = authLevel;
    }
}
// Localstorage logins
if(localStorage.getItem(userLogin) == null){
    var userLogins = [];
    userLogins.push(new userLogin("Benjamin", 4321,"1" ));
    userLogins.push(new userLogin("Mads",12345,"1"));
    userLogins.push(new userLogin("Simon",1234,"1"));
    userLogins.push(new userLogin("Jessica", 54321,"1"));
    // Logins for Projectmanagers
    userLogins.push(new userLogin("Oliver",1234,"2"));
    userLogins.push(new userLogin("Sara",4321,"2"));

    var userLoginstring = JSON.stringify(userLogins)
    localStorage.setItem("userLogin", userLoginstring)
} else {
    var employeeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userLogin"))
}
```

Comment: Please don't do this. Any user can easily see all user names and passwords since they are stored client side. Any user can also change their authLevel at will. This needs to be done on the server.

Comment: I understand, this is just for a school project :) We are not working with databases yet :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do you think it is possible to create a rolebased login system using Localstorage i Javascript?

It's possible to *create* it, but it will not be remotely secure. Any user will be able to gain any access they want, because **no** information held in the browser is hidden from a motivated user.

If you want to do this entirely in JavaScript, that's fine, just make sure some of the JavaScript is running on a *server*, store the authentication and role information server-side (you can echo the role information for the current user to the client for UI purposes), and gate-keep all actions server-side.

---

A couple of notes on the code in the question:

- Side note: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that constructor functions like your `userLogin` start with a capital letter (like `Date`, `Map`, etc. do), so `UserLogin`.
- It's odd to get `userLogins` in one branch of the `if` but `employeeList` in the other branch. Suggest ending up with just the one list of logins, not two depending on whether they're already there.
- `getItem` accepts a string key for the item to get, so this line:

  ```
  if(localStorage.getItem(userLogin) == null){
  ```

  will implicitly convert `userLogin` to a string and look up the value with that key. Your `userLogin` is a constructor function created using `class` syntax, which by default will convert to a string containing the code for the class, which probably isn't the key you want to use.

  From your later code, I suspect you wanted to do something like this (which also incorporates other feedback above):

  ```
  let userLogins = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userLogin"));
  if (!userLogins) {
      userLogins = [
          new UserLogin("Benjamin", 4321,"1" ),
          new UserLogin("Mads",12345,"1"),
          new UserLogin("Simon",1234,"1"),
          new UserLogin("Jessica", 54321,"1"),
          // Logins for Projectmanagers
          new UserLogin("Oliver",1234,"2"),
          new UserLogin("Sara",4321,"2"),
      ];
      localStorage.setItem("userLogin", JSON.stringify(userLogins));
  }
  // ...use `userLogins`
  ```

But again, this isn't at all secure. You've said you're doing it as the first step in a school project, though, so...